# C - format specifier for scanf?

Tags: c, scanf, format-specifiers

```
float lat, lon;
char info[50];

scanf("%f, %f, %49[^\n]", &lat, &lon, info);
```

In the above snippet, what kind of format specifier is `%49[^\n]`.

I do understand that it is the format specifier for the character array which is going to accept input upto 49 characters (+ the sentinal \0), and `[^\n]` looks like its a regex (although I had read somewhere that scanf doesn't support regex) OR a character set which is to expand to "any other character" that is NOT "newline" `\n`. Am I correct?

Also, why is there no `s` in the format specifier for writing into array info?

The program this snippet is from works. But is this good C style?

Comment: Did you read [the cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) on `scanf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specifier `%[` is a different conversion specifier from `%s`, even if it also must be paired with an argument of type `char *` (or `wchar_t *`). See e.g. the table [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

> [set]         matches a non-empty sequence of character from set of characters.
> *If the first character of the set is ^, then all characters not in the set are matched*. If the set begins with ] or ^] then the ] character is also included into the set. It is implementation-defined whether the character - in the non-initial position in the scanset may be indicating a range, as in [0-9]. If width specifier is used, matches only up to width. Always stores a null character in addition to the characters matched (so the argument array must have room for at least width+1 characters)

Comment: is [set] then a good format specifier if I am expecting strings containing spaces?

Comment: @computronium Yes, kinda (`scanf` is dangerous by itself). You could always use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and parse the line.

Answer (score 1):

My apologies, I incorrectly answered below.  If you can skip to the end, I'll give you the correct answer.

*** Incorrect Answer Begins ***

It would not be a proper format specifier, as there is no type.

```
%[parameter][flags][width][.precision][length]type
```

are the rules for a format statement.  As youc an see, the `type` is non-optional.  The author of this format item is thinking they can combine `regex` with `printf`, when the two have entirely different processing rules (and `printf` doesn't follow `regex`'s patterns)

*** Correct Answer Begins ***

`scanf` uses different format string rules than `printf`  Within `scanf`'s man page is this addition to `printf`'s rules

> [
>
> Matches a nonempty sequence of characters from the specified set
> of accepted characters; the next pointer must be a pointer to char,
> and there must be enough room for all the characters in the string,
> plus a terminating null byte. The usual skip of leading white space is
> suppressed. The string is to be made up of characters in (or not in) a
> particular set; the set is defined by the characters between the open
> bracket [ character and a close bracket ] character. The set excludes
> those characters if the first character after the open bracket is a
> circumflex (^). To include a close bracket in the set, make it the
> first character after the open bracket or the circumflex; any other
> position will end the set. The hyphen character - is also special;
> when placed between two other characters, it adds all intervening
> characters to the set. To include a hyphen, make it the last character
> before the final close bracket. For instance, [^]0-9-] means the set
> "everything except close bracket, zero through nine, and hyphen". The
> string ends with the appearance of a character not in the (or, with a
> circumflex, in) set or when the field width runs out.

Which basically means that `scanf` can scan with a subset of `regex`'s rules (the character set subset) but not all of `regex`'s rules

Comment: Why leave the old incorrect answer in? I'd remove that part.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I thnk it's a good idea to show the misconception; but, I might be wrong.  In any case, I don't like 100% reversing the answer without some explanation.